# Adding datepicker Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Not sure what I am doing incorrectly.  I add my datepicker class when the page loads.

```
 $(function()
 {
      $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", yearRange: "2002:"});
 });
```

I want to change my datepicker class to

```
   $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", yearRange: "2010:"});
```

On event I remove the class then unbind the datepicker, then rebind.

```
    $("#datefield").removeClass("datepicker hasDatepicker");
    $('#datefield').unbind();
    $('#datefield').bind();

    //rebind
    $("#datefield").datepicker();
```

how can I rebind the new datepicker?  I've removed the datepicker class then re-added the class.  Nothing seems to work.

Comment: I think I've got it correct.  `$("#datefield").datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", yearRange: "1998:"});`.  How can I add this using a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to store the element that you have initialized datepicker on, and then update its options using its own API thereafter:

```js
$(function() {
  var $dateField = $("#datefield").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    yearRange: "2002:"
  });
  
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $dateField.datepicker("option", { yearRange: "2010:" });
    console.log('Updated. Try opening datepicker again now');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datefield"></p>
<button type="button">Update year range to <code>2010:</code></button>
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about that.